# Centering buttons above a table

Tags: html, css, button, centering

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm having a difficult time spacing four buttons/an image to be aligned in the middle with my table. I tried just centering it but that didn't work...

Any help?

Here is a link to the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/40/)

Here is the html:

```
<center><img src="img"></center> 
       <center><a class="button" data-table="1" href="#">button</a>  
       <a class="button" data-table="2" href="#">button</a>
       <a class="button" data-table="3" href="#">button</a>
        <a class="button" data-table="4" href="#">button</a></center>

           <table id="1">        
            <thead>          
                <tr>
    <!-- Blank :) But you can enable this by removing "th:first-child{}" in css style :) -->
            <th>Feature</th> 
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th> Point</th>

            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table id="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
    <!-- Blank :) But you can enable this by removing "th:first-child{}" in css style :) -->
            <th>Feature</th> 
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th> Point</th>

            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>       
            </tbody>        
        </table>

        <table id="3">
            <thead>
               <tr>
    <!-- Blank :) But you can enable this by removing "th:first-child{}" in css style :) -->
            <th>Feature</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th> Point</th>


            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>       
        </tbody>
        </table>

        <table id="4">
            <thead>
               <tr>
    <!-- Blank :) But you can enable this by removing "th:first-child{}" in css style :) -->
            <th>Feature</th>        
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>

            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>        
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feature</th> 
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td><a href="link"></td>    
            </tr>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

a{
    margin: 0.5rem;    
}


a.button:nth-child(4) {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #878787;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #878787;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #878787;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #969595), color-stop(1, #787878));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #969595 5%, #787878 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #969595 5%, #787878 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #969595 5%, #787878 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #969595 5%, #787878 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #969595 5%, #787878 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#969595', endColorstr='#787878',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#969595;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
a.button:nth-child(4):hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #787878), color-stop(1, #969595));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #787878 5%, #969595 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #787878 5%, #969595 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #787878 5%, #969595 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #787878 5%, #969595 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #787878 5%, #969595 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#787878', endColorstr='#969595',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#787878;
}
a.button:nth-child(4):active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}





a.button:nth-child(3) {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #0b359e;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #0b359e;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #0b359e;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #003df5), color-stop(1, #1c49b0));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #003df5 5%, #1c49b0 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #003df5 5%, #1c49b0 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #003df5 5%, #1c49b0 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #003df5 5%, #1c49b0 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #003df5 5%, #1c49b0 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003df5', endColorstr='#1c49b0',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#003df5;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
a.button:nth-child(3):hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #1c49b0), color-stop(1, #003df5));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c49b0 5%, #003df5 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c49b0 5%, #003df5 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #1c49b0 5%, #003df5 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #1c49b0 5%, #003df5 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #1c49b0 5%, #003df5 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c49b0', endColorstr='#003df5',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#1c49b0;
}
a.button:nth-child(3):active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}



a.button:nth-child(2) {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #a38f1f;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #a38f1f;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #a38f1f;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fae13c), color-stop(1, #e0c21b));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fae13c 5%, #e0c21b 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fae13c 5%, #e0c21b 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fae13c 5%, #e0c21b 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fae13c 5%, #e0c21b 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fae13c 5%, #e0c21b 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fae13c', endColorstr='#e0c21b',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#fae13c;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
a.button:nth-child(2):hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e0c21b), color-stop(1, #fae13c));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e0c21b 5%, #fae13c 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e0c21b 5%, #fae13c 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e0c21b 5%, #fae13c 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e0c21b 5%, #fae13c 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e0c21b 5%, #fae13c 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e0c21b', endColorstr='#fae13c',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#e0c21b;
}
a.button:nth-child(2):active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}




a.button:nth-child(1){
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #e84b52;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #e84b52;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #e84b52;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fa202b), color-stop(1, #db1c2f));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa202b 5%, #db1c2f 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa202b 5%, #db1c2f 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fa202b 5%, #db1c2f 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa202b 5%, #db1c2f 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fa202b 5%, #db1c2f 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fa202b', endColorstr='#db1c2f',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#fa202b;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}

a.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #db1c2f), color-stop(1, #fa202b));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #db1c2f 5%, #fa202b 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #db1c2f 5%, #fa202b 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #db1c2f 5%, #fa202b 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #db1c2f 5%, #fa202b 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #db1c2f 5%, #fa202b 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#db1c2f', endColorstr='#fa202b',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#db1c2f;
}
a.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


/*** CSS of Pricing Table ***/

/** Start of General **/

/* Background */

body { background-image:url("images/texture.jpg"); background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; position:relative; min-width:1400px; font-family: "Arial"; font-size:18px; }

/** End of General **/


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/** Pricing Table (You need this. Anything else above is just for background) **/

table {
    width:1214px;
    height:520px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: .5em auto;
    font-family: "Arial"; 
    font-size:18px; 
}

th{
    width:304px;
    height:100px;
    outline:none;
    background: #30383b; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #30383b 0%, #272f32 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#30383b), color-stop(100%,#272f32)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #30383b 0%,#272f32 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #30383b 0%,#272f32 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #30383b 0%,#272f32 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #30383b 0%,#272f32 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#30383b', endColorstr='#272f32',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:white;
    border-top: 1px solid #484d50;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #484d50;

}

th:first-child{ /* You can enable it or remove it and you will see, what it change :) */
    background:none;
    border:none;
    font-size:0px;
}

td {
    width:304px;
    height:73px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#31383b;
    background: #cd922a; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cd922a 0%, #865e17 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(100%,#e9e9e9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #cd922a 0%,#865e17 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #cd922a 0%,#865e17 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #cd922a 0%,#865e17 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #cd922a 0%,#865e17 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#e9e9e9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    border: 1px solid #000000;

}

tr > td#bgtitle{
    background: #FA202B; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FA202B 0%, #e01620 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ec6b59), color-stop(100%,#dc5a49)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #FA202B 0%,#e01620 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #FA202B 0%,#e01620 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FA202B 0%,#e01620 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FA202B 0%,#e01620 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec6b59', endColorstr='#dc5a49',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:white;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #e01620;
    border-right: 1px solid #e01620;

}
tr > td#bgtitlet{
    background: #FAE13C; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FAE13C 0%, #bca71b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ec6b59), color-stop(100%,#dc5a49)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FAE13C 0%,#dac431 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #FAE13C 0%,#bca71b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FAE13C 0%,#bca71b 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAE13C 0%,#bca71b 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec6b59', endColorstr='#c1ae30',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:white;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #bca71b;
    border-right: 1px solid #bca71b;

}
tr > td#bgtitletw{
    background: #003DF5; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #003DF5 0%, #003ae0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ec6b59), color-stop(100%,#dc5a49)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FAE13C 0%,#003ae0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #003DF5 0%,#003ae0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #003DF5 0%,#003ae0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003DF5 0%,#003ae0 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec6b59', endColorstr='#dc5a49',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:white;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #003ae0;
    border-right: 1px solid #003ae0;

}

tr > td#bgtitlef{
    background: #B3B3B3; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #B3B3B3 0%, #969595 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ec6b59), color-stop(100%,#dc5a49)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #B3B3B3 0%,#969595 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #B3B3B3 0%,#969595 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #B3B3B3 0%,#969595 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #B3B3B3 0%,#969595 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec6b59', endColorstr='#dc5a49',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:white;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #969595;
    border-right: 1px solid #969595;

}

tr > td a:active{
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    width:124px;
    outline:none;
    background: #dc5a49; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dc5a49 0%, #818080 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dc5a49), color-stop(100%,#ec6b59)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dc5a49 0%,#818080 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #dc5a49 0%,#818080 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #dc5a49 0%,#818080 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #dc5a49 0%,#818080 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dc5a49', endColorstr='#ec6b59',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

/** End of Pricing Table **/

/*** End of CSS for Pricing Table ***/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*** You can remove this (you don't need it) ***/

/** Start of Social Icons **/

/* SOCIAL ICONS - GENERAL */

.social { 
list-style:none; width:41px; float:right; right:48px; top:-19px; position:absolute;
}

.social li { 
float:left; left:10px; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding:5px;
}

.social li a { 
display:block; width:48px; height:48px; margin-right:15px; position:relative; text-decoration:none; outline:none;
}

.social li a strong { 
 font-size:13px; margin-top:6px; font-weight:normal; position:absolute; right:64px; top:-1px; color:#fff; padding:3px; z-index:9999; white-space:nowrap; 
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -moz-border-radius:3px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-border-radius:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius:3px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

li.deviantart { background-image:url("images/deviantart.png"); }

/* SOCIAL ICONS - CSS3 */

#css3:hover li { opacity:0.2; }

#css3 li { 
    opacity:0.2; transition-property: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity; -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
     -moz-transition-property: opacity; -moz-transition-duration: 500ms; 
     -o-transition-property: opacity; -o-transition-duration: 500ms; 
 }
#css3 li a strong { 
    opacity:0; transition-property: 300ms;
     -webkit-transition-property: opacity, top; -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;transition-duration: 300ms; filter: alpha(opacity=0);
     -moz-transition-property: opacity, top; -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
      -o-transition-property: opacity, top; -o-transition-duration: 300ms; 
  }

#css3 li:hover { opacity:1; }
#css3 li:hover a strong { opacity:1; top:-10px; }

/** End of Social Icons **/

/*** You can remove this (you don't need it) ***/
tr:nth-child(even){
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I learned something new from each of you. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out from the fact that you really don't want to see the first-child of `th`, and if this is the case, I'd suggest you remove those lines from each row and also the reference to it in your css file.

I corrected your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/50/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `HTML` with mine

```
<div style="width:60%;margin-left:30%">
   <a class="button" data-table="1" href="#">button</a>  
   <a class="button" data-table="2" href="#">button</a>
   <a class="button" data-table="3" href="#">button</a>
   <a class="button" data-table="4" href="#">button</a>
</div>
```

Key is to put all the buttons in a `div` which is of same width of your table and then centering the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It already is centered with your table.

You have

```
th:first-child {
    background: none;
}
```

so you can't see that part of the table.

Remove that `background: none;` and you will be able to see that it's centered.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/46/

Also, if you're using HTML5, don't use `<center>` tags, since they are deprecated in HTML5. Just use `<div>` tags instead, and give them `text-align: center;`